# Controlling light using midi inputs

Tags: midi, light, philips-hue, max-msp-jitter

I currently am using Max/MSP to create an interactive system between lights and sound.

I am using Philips hue lighting which I have hooked up to Max/MSP and now I am wanting to trigger an increase in brightness/saturation on the input of a note from a Midi instrument. Does anyone have any ideas how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

I have built this.
I used the [shell](http://www.maxobjects.com/?v=objects&id_objet=1194&requested=shell&operateur=AND&id_plateforme=&id_format=&PHPSESSID=95acb17eeba66661419fe5a5a52b4597) object. And then feed an array of parameters into it via a javascipt file with the HUE API. There is a lag time of 1/6 of a second between commands.

Javascript file:

```
inlets=1;
outlets=1;
var bridge="192.168.0.100";
var hash="newdeveloper";
var bulb= 1;
var brt= 200;
var satn= 250;
var hcolor= 10000;
var bulb=1;

function list(bulb,hcolor,brt,satn,tran) {
 execute('PUT','http://'+bridge+'/api/'+hash+'/lights/'+bulb+'/state', '"{\\\"on\\\":true,\\\"hue\\\":'+hcolor+', \\\"bri\\\":'+brt+',\\\"sat\\\":'+satn+',\\\"transitiontime\\\":'+tran+'}"');
}
function execute($method,$url,$message){

outlet(0,"curl --request",$method,"--data",$message,$url);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To control Philips Hue you need to issue calls to a restful http based api, like so: http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/core-concepts, using the [jweb] or [maxweb] objects: https://cycling74.com/forums/topic/making-rest-call-from-max-6-and-saving-the-return/

Generally however, to control lights you use DMX, the standard protocol for professional lighting control. Here is a somewhat lengthy post on the topic: https://cycling74.com/forums/topic/controlling-video-and-lighting-with-max/, scroll down to my post from APRIL 11, 2014 | 3:42 AM.

Answer (score 0):

To change the bri/sat of your lights is explained in the following link (Registration/Login required)
http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/lights-api#16_set_light_state

You will need to know the IP Address of your hue hue bridge which is explained here: http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/getting-started and a valid username.
Also bear in mind the performance limitations.  As a general rule you can send up to 10 lightstate commands per second.   I would recommend having a 100ms gap between each one, to prevent flooding the bridge (and losing commands).

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in finding out details of who to map this data from a MIDI input to the phillips HUE lights within max? or are you already familiar with Max. 
Using Tommy b's javascript (which you could put into a js object), You could for example scale the MIDI messages you want to use using *midiin* and *borax* objects and map them to the outputs you want using the *scale* object. Karlheinz Essl's RTC library is a good place to start with algorithmic composition if you want to transform the data at all http://www.essl.at/software.html

Comment: @bish did you see the maxpatch in the link I gave you? Isn't it helpful? because you didn't up-vote my comment

Answer (score 0):

+1 for DMX light control via Max.  There are lots of good max-to-dmx tutorials and USB-DMX hardware is getting pretty cheap.  However, as someone who previously believed in dragging a bunch of computer equipment on stage just to control a light or two with an instrument, I'd recommend researching and purchasing a simple one channel "color organ" circuit kit (e.g., Velleman MK 110).  Controlling a 120/240V light bulb via audio is easier than you might think; a computer for this type of application is usually overkill. Keep it simple and good luck!